# What is the correct way of using nativeID / working with RCTRootView subviews in React Native?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have an existing iOS app and I am using react native's `RCTRootView` to draw some components for my app.

```
// swift
private lazy var RNContent: RCTRootView = {
    let mockData:NSDictionary = ["someProps": self.someProps]
    let RNContent = RCTRootView(bridge: self.bridge, moduleName: "RNContent", initialProperties: mockData as [NSObject : AnyObject])!
    return RNContent
  }()

// JS
AppRegistry.registerComponent('RNContent', () => component);
```

---

Here is what my RN hierarchy looks like

```
<View>
  <View>
   <Text />
   <ScrollView /> <--
  <View>
</View>
```

I want to get a hold of this `ScrollView` on the native side. As per the docs `nativeID` should help. However, I can't see any subviews inside the `RCTRootView` that I define in JS side. In fact, root view only has a single subview called `RCTRootContentView` which does not have any further subviews available.

So my question is what is the correct way to get hold of the subviews of `RCRootView` on the native side?

I have tried a few things like, using the `UIManager`'s `addUIBlock` to get hold of the view register, but I think there is an obvious point I am missing related to the `RCTRootView` and how it works.

Interestingly, if I directly use a natively registered component (registered via `RCT_EXTERN_MODULE`) in my RN hierarchy I can see that this component is detached from the `RCTRootContentView` and it also has a nativeID that I assigned to it on the JS side.

```
 RCTExecuteOnUIManagerQueue {
      self.bridge.uiManager.addUIBlock { (uiManager: RCTUIManager?, viewRegistry:[NSNumber : UIView]?) in

        uiManager?.view(forNativeID: "SelfAssignedID", withRootTag: self. RNContent.reactTag) // nil

        viewRegistry?.forEach({ (key: NSNumber, value: UIView) in
          print("Test1: ", key, value.nativeID) // only native components has nativeID, which does makes sense because RCTRootContentView doesn't have subviews... but why not? is there a way to get hold of them? If not, why not?
        })
      }
    }
```

---

Any help would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In fact, root view only has a single subview called RCTRootContentView which does not have any further subviews available.

This seems like an issue to me. The `<Text/>` node in JS should be creating a `UITextView` child in the native content view. Maybe try actually adding some content to `<Text/>` and `<ScrollView/>` to get it to render?

> I want to get a hold of this ScrollView on the native side.

Can you give some more context on what you're trying to do? I have a feeling `nativeID` API isn't what you want to use.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for answering, I just had to select the view for nativeID once the component tree had mounted and apparently It was only a timing issue. The nativeID works as I suspected.

I figured it out the other day and forgot to close this question, which I will do now.